# Which graphic tablets support tilt?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing-tablet

Have been googling my eyes out, besides marketing blabla I couldn't find good information at all...

There are several graphic tablet producers:

- Wacom
- Aiptek
- Genius
- [etc...](http://pixelpinch.com/2011/04/best-handpicked-graphic-tablets-for-artists-designers)

Of course **Wacom** is the best. But they are also pretty expensive. Wacoms Intuos4 supports tilt (Bamboo does not).

I am looking for a cheaper alternative to Wacom. I basically want an A5 tablet with a pen having tilt (and maybe rotation) support. Is Wacom the only one offering this? I don't care about buttons or anything else.

Also: Wacom seems to be the **only** ones supporting rotation of the pen (with the Art Pen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hanvon drawing tablets do have tilt feature. Though they are not exactly cheapest of the cheapest drawing tablets.

[Hanvon](http://en.hw99.com/show-5-4-1.html) - Not all of them have tilt I believe, so check for Tilt in the "Technical specifications". Art masters do have it.

---

You asked if there are any others and I was like "Can't remember any other ones- Trust..."

[Trust](http://www.trust.com/en/trust/graphic-tablets) - The 3 newest ones seem to have tilt. ..and the pens seem to work without batteries nowadays..

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with Wacom. They're expensive, but simply good. Also, I'd took into consideration tablet's ability to trace stylus rotation. In my experience it's even more useful than tilt. Be adviced though: not all Wacom styli support it.

Comment: You're right about that, but only the Art Pen supports rotation, which would be additional $s. Right now I'm looking at Intuos vs. Trust and whether I really need tilt - rotation does seem very interesting!

Comment: @moontear Also, wacom still has the most accessories. Which is good to keep in mind...

Comment: I understand very well importance of the price :) – I'm on a tight budget :). I only want to suggest you to consider another requirement for your purchase. Pen rotation can save you a lot of trouble if you do a digital painting.

Comment: I guess that's why my Intuos4 never seems to respond to pen rotation reliably. Though even its tilt function acts a little goofy. I mean, in the config tool, everything registers fine. But when I actually set a brush parameter to tilt, it never does what I expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

People who like to do digital painting may also find tilt useful as the hairs of a brush can be simulated in programs like Corel Painter where the shape of the digital brush changes with angle just like a real paint brush which can be spread out when pushed into the canvas, or thin lines if gently brushed, or thick lines if tilted.

Wacom tablets with tilt include some Intuos type  , Intuos Pro series , and the Cintiq line.

XP-Pen Drawing Tablets with tilt have one  XP-Pen Artist 15.6 Pro [Digital Art Pad With Screen](https://www.xp-pen.com) . the graphic tablet without screen called : XP-Pen Deco Pro (9x6 Inch and 11x6 Inch active area two type ) also come with 60 degrees of pen tilt function. the stylus is battery-free .

Personally I feel Apple's tilt implementation is the best. Wacom works, but it's less reliable than Apple's, sometimes mid-tilt it stops being recognized and lays down a no-tilt stroke, then comes back. Plus, Wacom pens have thin nibs that make combining tilt and pressure slightly more difficult than on the Apple Pencil.